# ruby Aws-sdk v2 public url access denied issue

Tags: ruby, aws-sdk

I'm using aws-sdk '2.0.29' for uploading csv files to S3. Ending up with access denied issue when accessing the public_url.

```
 s3_credentials = Aws::Credentials.new(S3_CREDENTIALS['access_key_id'],S3_CREDENTIALS['secret_access_key']) #creating credentials object
 s3_bucket = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region: ['region'], credentials: s3_credentials).bucket(S3_CREDENTIALS['bucket']) #finding bucket
 object = s3_bucket.objects(s3_file_path) #creating an object
 object.upload_file(file_to_upload)#uploading file to s3
 object.public_url #fetching the uploaded file url from s3
```

Can someone help me with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You uploaded the object to Amazon S3 without specifying an "ACL" (access control list). The simple fix is to specify a 'public-read' ACL when you upload the object:

```
 object.upload_file(file_to_upload, acl:'public-read')
```

When you upload a file with a 'public-read' ACL, the object may be downloaded by **anyone**. If you prefer to make it only accessible to particular users, then you can provide a customized ACL, or you can omit the ACL and instead use pre-signed URL:

```
 object.presigned_url(:get)
 #=> 'https://...'
```

A pre-signed URL provides temporary access to a private object in Amazon S3. A presigned URL expires after a set amount of time, defaulting to 15 minutes.

Comment: you can also specify "ACL" with presigned_url `object.presigned_url(:put, {acl: 'public-read'})`

Comment: Remember to setup the related policy when using `public-read` (in particular: `PutObjectAcl`), as indicated here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32339576/1252245